# JQUERY & php post error 500 (server internal error)

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am stuck with an error in a webapp that I am developing, I am sure that it is quite basic error.

Whenever I run this code in the web the chromium debbuger return me this error:

```
 POST http://my_ip/server_wrapper.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

1. PHP server works properly, phpinfo() returns the whole information correctly
2. The web server is Apache.
3. Iptables is completly open, and I am just using it under LAN.
4. The permission of all the file in the web root directory are 755.

Here is the JQUERY, js file fragment"

```
this.post    = function () {
 $.post ("server_wrapper.php",
  {
   _id:          this.id,
   _question:    this.question,
   _type:        "none"
  },
  function (data, status) {
   alert ("DATA: " + data + " status: " + status);
  }
 );
}
```

Here is the php file:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["_question"]) && isset($_POST["_type"]) && isset($_POST["_id"])) {

$question = $_POST["_question"];
$type     = $_POST["_type"];
$id       = $_POST["_id"];

$con      = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connecto to db";

} else {
    mysqli_query ($con, "INSERT INTO questions (id, question, type) VALUES ('$id','$question','$type')");
}

mysqli_close ($con);
 }
?>
```

## EDIT

This is what the log return over and over again:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/server_wrapper.php
```

Comment: what is in your server error logs?

Comment: `tail -F /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: you don't have the mysqli extension, what OS are you running ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**To show errors on page:**

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
?>
```

First will enable error display on the page itself instead of generating 500 error.

Second will make sure all errors are reported. This includes Notices.

*Advice: Write code that does not even fire one notice.*

**To find the PHP error log file:**

```
grep error_log /etc/php.ini
grep ^error_log /etc/php.ini
```

**To install MySQL on RedHat family servers:**

```
yum install mysql.x86_64
yum install mysql mysql-server
chkconfig --level 2345 mysqld on
service mysqld start
mysqladmin -u root password somepassword
```

**I recommend you use the following repos if you want to have access to the latest PHP version.**

```
wget http://mirrors.coreix.net/fedora-epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

To install:

```
rpm -Uvh remi-release-*.rpm epel-release-*.rpm
/bin/rm epel-release-*.noarch.rpm remi-release-*.rpm
perl -pi -e 's/enabled=0/enabled=1/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
yum update (optional - not recommended unless you know what you are doing)
yum install yum-plugin-priorities
```

Make sure after you install the repos you edit them and set enabled to 0 that way you can use them selectively only as you should.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,epel install whatever
```

Comment: Best to keep that off, and look at the error log for errors. You don't want this to ever be on in production, and I don't trust it to be in my codebase in the first place.

Comment: He has no idea where the error logs are and I did not want to start asking about configurations and distributions only for him to find a huge log. This is a good solution to his problem. I did not say it is a best practice to have it on functional code. That is another topic. See my advice.

Comment: Thanks for your help its shown me the error, that it was about mysqli_connect function

Comment: Depending on distro, php.ini could also be in `/etc/php5/*/php.ini`

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the mysqli extension is not installed or enabled. Check your php.ini for the line `extension=mysqli.so`, otherwise enable it or install it with `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`